# How to quit from a community?

Tags: support

I tried to quit from the musical community, I logged off, I tried to follow the instructions that I found in other responses here in Meta, but no matter what I do, I still have a user account there. How can I quit from a community?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a delete link on your profile page there?

Comment: @Oded he does have a question.  Isn't that only an option for accounts without posts?

Comment: Yeah there should be a delete link. if all else fails, make a new acct

Comment: @Servy - "If your account has never voted or posted a question or answer **more than once**, you should see a self-delete option on your user page"

Comment: @Oded Didn't know that.  But in any case, he's voted 7 times, so no, he won't have such a link.

Comment: I don't have this link. I realized that I'm not so good at music to be able to help there or to even post questions that people would answer and I would prefer not to be in the community.

Comment: thank you for the "please delete me" hint.

Comment: @Oded How can I unlink my account from a specific community? I want to quit from only one community. Don't want to delete network profile